# Ruby: Dynamically defining class methods in a module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm having trouble dynamically defining class methods within a module. See code below. I get a `NameError: undefined local variable or method` when trying to reference another class method in the module. Seems like this might be a scope or context issue, but I've not been able to figure it out so far.

```
module Bar

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods

    def fruits
      ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
    end

    def example_function(string)
      string.upcase
    end

    fruits.each do |fruit|
      method_name = fruit.to_sym
      define_method(method_name) { example_function(fruit) }
    end

  end

end

class Foo
  include Bar
end

puts Foo.apple
puts Foo.orange
puts Foo.banana
```

I want to be able to call:

```
puts Foo.apple => "APPLE"
puts Foo.orange => "ORANGE"
puts Foo.banana => "BANANA"
```

Currently when I try any of these I get the following error:
`NameError: undefined local variable or method 'fruits' for Bar::ClassMethods:Module`

Additionally, class methods in Bar::ClassMethods should be available to Foo, so I should be able to call:

```
puts Foo.fruits => ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
```

Requirements:

1. All code is within a single module.
2. The module allows mixing both instance and class methods (article below).
3. The target methods are dynamically defined.

*Read "Include vs Extend in Ruby" (esp. section titled "A Common Idiom") http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/*

Help with this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, the `fruits` method is defined as an instance method, but you are calling it without an instance on `ClassMethods`. Just define it like this:

```
def self.fruits
  ["apple", "orange", "banana"]
end
```

And your code works.

EDIT:
To make the `fruits` method accessible as a class method on `Foo` too, you have to declare the `fruits` array in a way that is accessible while inside the `ClassMethods` module. One way would be to declare the array as a class variable and use it in the `fruits` method and the `each` block. Look at the following code:

```
module Bar

  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    @@fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]

    def fruits
      @@fruits
    end

    def example_function(string)
      string.upcase
    end

    @@fruits.each do |fruit|
      method_name = fruit.to_sym
      define_method(method_name) { example_function(fruit) }
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar
end

puts Foo.apple
puts Foo.orange
puts Foo.banana
puts Foo.fruits
```

Comment: Hey Mario, your code did fix my initial example, but I neglected to clarify that I want to be able to access Foo.fruits, see updated version. Everything in the Bar::ClassMethods module should be a valid class method in Foo by virtue of the module pattern in use, even without defining the functions with self.

Comment: @mayatron I updated my answer. Hope this works as you intended.